# How to hide / show a button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and three buttons on the bottom, lets say A, B, and C. When I click on A it needs to disappear and the B and C need to be the only ones that are shown. After clicking on either B or C, the button A needs to reappear again. jQuery is what I need to use.

Comment: Please show some sample html and your attempts to solve this yourself. Stackoverlfow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. Take some time to read [ask] for reference

Comment: I am reading a book about jQuery now. I would be able to hide the button, but I am not sure how to connect it with the other two buttons and make it appear again, if one of these is clicked.

Comment: At least put a [mcve] together before asking. Sites like jsfiddle.net , codepen, jsbin etc are also helpful sandbox sites for testing and forking examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has two functions `show` and `hide`:

```
$('#a').click(function(){
  $('#a').hide();
});

$('#b').click(function(){
  $('#a').show();
});

$('#c').click(function(){
  $('#a').show();
});
```

Comment: it depends on which selectors he will use, that was the fastest and clearest way

Answer (score -1):

Hello you need to use the "addClass" and "removeClass" methods

steps:

Add Id to each Button, Let's say the Id of "A" is "A" you can hide the button "A" this way:
      $("#A").addClass("hidden")
and show it this way
      $("#A").removeClass("hidden")

define the class "hidden" using CSS:

.hidden
{
display : none
}